# Detect if tab has focus in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, bash, tabs, mdi, gnome-terminal

From within the command line, how can I detect if the terminal running the command is associated with the gnome-terminal tab that has focus?

Ultimately, I am trying to make the terminal play a sound when any long running command finishes, except those that I'm actively interacting with.

I have a my terminal configured using `trap "..." debug` and `$COMMAND_PROMPT` such that it plays a sound when any long running command finishes, but that includes commands that take user input like `man`.  I figured an elegant solution to the interactive process problem would be to only play the sound if the tab does not have focus, but I'm struggling to find a way to do so.